# jQuery focus the input in the next tr -> td when that td contains an input field, but never focus html select

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, html-table, focus

I have the following html:

```
<tr>
  <td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="a"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address</td><td><input type="text" name="b"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Type</td><td><select name="c"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Gender</td><td><input type="text" name="d"></td>
</tr>
```

If the user is in input 'a' and presses the tab key, I have it working now that the focus goes to input 'b'. However, once the user tabs while in input 'b', nothing happens. I would like jQuery to skip the select field 'c' and focus input 'd'.

Right now I use this and it works fine but it permits the user to tab the select into focus...instead i want it to ignore the select and try and focus the input in the tr and td after it:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('input:text').first().focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use -1 in the tab index to remove it from the order.

```
<select tabindex="-1">
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to traverse all text inputs with TAB key a solution is:

```js
$(function () {
  $(':text').on('keydown', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 9) { // on tab go to next input
      // prevent the default action
      e.preventDefault();
      
      // select the next row containing a text input field (skip select!)
      // and get the first element
      var nextInput = $(e.target).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').filter(function(index, element) {
        return $(element).find(':text').length > 0;
      }).first().find(':text');
      
      // if next input exists go there, else go to the first one
      if (nextInput.length == 0) {
        $(':text:first').focus();
      } else {
        nextInput.focus();
      }
    }
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="a"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adress</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="b"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td><select name="c"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="d"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```